# Why does WEEKDAY function has duplicated return_type behavior?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

**TLDR:**

What's the difference between behavior of this two lines regards the `return_type` parameter since they return same value?

```
WEEKDAY(44277,2)

WEEKDAY(44277,11)
```

**Long explanation:**

According to [official Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/weekday-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a) the last parameter of WEEKDAY function is regard the return type you should expect.

But I realized some options look ambiguous, like 2 and 11, as you can see here:

```
WEEKDAY(44277,2)
```

Returns 2 (Monday)

```
WEEKDAY(44277,11)
```

Returns 2 (Monday)

[image: Image in documentation showing the duplicate]

What is the use of this difference?

Comment: just a guess, but probably has to do with backwards and other spreadsheet app compatibility.

Comment: [This Article](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/04/16/excel-weekday-day-functions/) would support that.  Before Excel 2010 11-17 were not available.  So Excel kept the `1,2,3` for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Both 2 & 11 represents days Monday to Saturday, since the date you are using is 22/30/2021 that's Y returns Monday,,, what's wrong with it !! Command has types represents Weekdays patters around the Globe ☺

Comment: @RajeshS There is no point in having two parameter with the exact same behavior. Since this numbers were used to keep compatibility like `Scott-Craner` I don't understand the point in create the option 11 since you could use 2 instead. Those number are already broken (1-3, 11-17) so no "elegance" was provided too. It could be (1-3, 10-17) and it would look ugly anyway. So no point in duplication. In this case I would thought there is a good reason. ;)

Comment: @VitorCanova ,, Excel has many such parameters in case of SUBTOTAL & others,,, please raise your concern to the Microsoft Developers Team,,, !!